# Place figure just as you would a glyph/character

Tags: floats, symbols, wrap, inline

I would like to use a figure inline - and by that I *literally* mean having it inside the line of text. I want to display it in parentheses to illustrate what symbol I am referring to - these symbols are a few very simple traffic signs and can be distinguished at those sizes.

I have tried a few wrapfig approaches but they always put my figure to the side of the text and never quite align correctly with the text height - I'm wondering whether there's any better way to do this.

What this should look like (imagine that **♫** is a figure and not a glyph):

> This is the musical note I am referring to: **♫**. And it is totally awesome that I can show it to you inline.

Comment: Just add the `\includegraphics` in the text, you don't need any `figure` or `wrapfig` environment to add images.

Comment: Yep, it apparently is ^^